# Import Automation for Mobile Studio - 'File Not Found' error

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, import, ftp

I'm running a file-drop triggered automation to import people from a CSV list into a MobileConnect Contact List. I've created the Import Definition - very simple, just 3 fields (contact key, mobile no and locale). I've tested the import definition and mapped the fields and it works fine.

I've just built an Automation in Automation Studio for it, with only this one step (Import Mobile Contacts). It is triggered by a File Drop on our FTP, and a file naming pattern of **begins with 'SMS_'**. However when I run the automation, it fails every time.

I get the error

'File SMS_Master2.csv not found'

I don't understand - how is it not finding the file? The trigger of it arriving is what started the automation.

Any pointers?

Comment: First Drop the file local to Ftp server then configure the Import Activity in Automation Studio i think file is not there in Ftp check properly

Comment: It is in the FTP server - that's what's triggering the automation

Answer (score 1):

The issue sounds like your naming convention is off.  If, for instance, your file is named SMS_Maaster2.csv - then it will run the automation, but fail the import. Since all the automation looks for is that it begins with 'SMS_' where the import looks for the exact name of 'SMS_Master2.csv'.

My first action would be to verify the name and see if there needs to be adjustment there.

If all seems correct there, then I would try using the personalization string `%%FILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER%%` ([ref](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/112907/file-naming-convention-for-automated-data-import-exact-target)) inside your Import instead of the actual name of the file. This will pull in the file that triggered your automation, no matter what it is named. This string is now no longer documented (no idea why...), but it still functions correctly. This string will only work for an import activity inside of a triggered automation.

Comment: I'm using begins with 'SMS_' for the trigger and I'm using %%FILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER%% in the import definition, and the automation does start, so it's clearly seeing the file drop in, but then immediately gives me the error.

Comment: Did you make sure the file location in the import  was aimed at the correct subdirectory?

Comment: Yes, we only have one. It's strange - it says 'File Master2.csv not found'. Then I tried another test file called Master3.csv and it said 'File Master3.csv not found'. So it can clearly find it but won't pull it through!

Comment: Try putting in the exact name of the file into the import AND the trigger automation then try that. Also, it seems to be pulling just the second part of the file,name not the SMS_ part that is in front of it. e.g. SMS_Master2.csv is triggering it, but import is looking for Master2.csv